# How does Django cache system works?

Tags: django-cache, django-caching

How does Django cache system works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Django comes with a robust cache system that lets you save dynamic
>   pages so they don't have to be calculated for each request. For
>   convenience, Django offers different levels of cache granularity: You
>   can cache the output of specific views, you can cache only the pieces
>   that are difficult to produce, or you can cache your entire site.

Check this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs)